# PHP file not found even though curl can find it

Tags: php, curl

I'm creating a file in PHP and then save it as

```
$job->fullFileName = realpath(".")."/abc.txt";
```

If I use this path in CURL (to send an email with other services), then it works properly. The email I received has an attachment as expected. So obviously the file exists and CURL could read it.

```
    $fileContent = '';
    if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
        // php 5.6+
        $fileContent = curl_file_create($job->fullFileName);
    } else {
        $fileContent = '@' . realpath($job->fullFileName);
    }

    $params = array(
        ....
        'files['.$job->fileName.'.epub'.']' => $fileContent
      );

    print_r($params);

    $request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

    // Generate curl request
    $session = curl_init($request);

    // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

    // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    // Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // obtain response
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);
```

But when I try to allow the user to download it directly, PHP did not find it:

```
$app->get('/download', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    $params = $request->query;
    $id = (int)$params->get('id', '');
    if (!$id) {
        return new Response("Job not found", 404);
    }

    $job = Job::fromId($app, $id);
    if (!$job->fullFileName) {
        return new Response("File not found", 404);
    }

    if (!file_exists($job->fullFileName)) {
        return new Response("PHP give up", 404); //<<<------ IT RETURN THIS LINE!!!
    }

    $app['monolog']->error("[api.download] attempt to download $job->fullFileName");
    // Without the check above, it will throw File Not found exception right here
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($job->fullFileName);
    $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT);
    return $response;
});
```

What did I miss?

Comment: does there any errors / exceptions ?

Comment: @hassan no, it's just return false and if I try to open it, it throw File not found exception.

Comment: ok it's unclear , please provide more snippets about your code